# Counting Mails in Outlook with Autohotkey

Tags: outlook, autohotkey, outlook-2016

I tried to write a script, that counts the e-Mails in a specific public exchange folder in outlook.
If there are Mails in subfolder2, a Messagebox should open and tell me, how many Mails there are. I tried this, but it did not work.

```
    Outlook := ComObjActive("Outlook.Application")
    mail = (Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder(18).Folders("Subfolder\Subfolder2")
    if (mail.Items.Count>0)
    {
    msgbox % mail.Items.Count "Mails in folder"
    }
    else
    {
    msgbox No Mails.
    }
```

Does anyone has a idea, how I should change the script, that it works?

Comment: What does " it did not work" mean? Did you get an error?

Comment: It does not count the mails in the folder i want. The Script works, no errors. Just not the way, i want it to work.

Comment: and only the else statement is triggered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. 
I simply removed the Variable.

```
 Outlook := ComObjActive("Outlook.Application")
    if (Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder(18).Folders("Subfolder").Folders("Subfolder2").Items.Count>0)
    {
    msgbox % Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder(18).Folders("Subfolder").Folders("Subfolder2").Items.Count "Mails in folder"
    }
    else
    {
    msgbox No Mails.
    }
```

Thanks for the help :D

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use this:

mail := Outlook.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder(18).Folders("Subfolder\Subfolder2")

Comment: sadly, it did not work. I still get the "else", although there are mails in the folder.

Answer (score 0):

You must retrieve subfoldersone at a time, you cannot specify a path. Change the line

```
 mail = (Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder(18).Folders("Subfolder\Subfolder2")
```

to

```
 mail = (Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder(18).Folders("Subfolder").Folders("Subfolder2")
```

Comment: I still get the "No Mails" Message... I do not even know what folder the script accesses

Comment: What does mail.Name return?

Comment: an empty messagebox

Comment: That would probably mean mail variable is null. I don't know how/if autohotkey handles COM exceptions, but apparently you are not accessing that folder correctly.